# Why do Chi-Square distribution and Poisson look similar

Tags: poisson-distribution, gamma-distribution, chi-squared-distribution

I am new to statistics and I am looking at [Chi-Squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution), and I found that it looks similar to [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution).

Is there any theoretical relation between them, or its just coincidental?

I have seen this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2427795/relationship-between-chi-square-distribution-and-poisson-distribution) on math.stackexchange but appears too mathematical.

Is there any simpler explanation for a dummy like me?

Comment: They model two different things. One works for real values of $x$, the other for only integers. So that although one can "convert" between them, what appears to be lacking is any motive for doing so.

Comment: Well... they're both right skew but so are an infinity of other distributions. They're not *especially* alike, though there are connections between them besides their superficially similar appearance.

Comment: Chi-squared distribution is one kind of gamma distribution. More generally we can say, I guess, there is a relationship between gamma distribution and Poisson distribution.  Let's assume the situation, as your wikipedia link said, that the events occurs 'constant rate and independently of the time since the last event'. Then, Poisson distribution is the distribution of the number of events for a certain length of time and gamma distribution is the distribution of waiting time needed to see a certain number of events. So they are closely related. Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Welcome to our site. Poisson distributions count events, while Gamma distributions give waiting times to those events.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Related_distributions_and_properties.  I have described and exploited this relationship in answers at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/287025/919 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/353134/919.